# How to calculate rotation angle from proportion of two values?

Tags: javascript, php, python-3.x, math

There is a couple of indicators that shows kill/death and dealt/received damage on [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20140612122907if_/http://worldoftanks.eu/community/accounts/500576401-Lenecromonger/). There is no client-side JavaScript function that would calculate the rotation angle for arrows on them, only the one that converts `transform: rotate();` property to legacy IE's DXImage thing.

The initial position of both arrows (when ratio is 1) is 0°, the leftmost is -30° (ratio is 0), the rightmost is 30° (ratio is 2), but this is applicable to the first (kill/death) indicator.

The right one is complicated, as it may have variable lowest and highest values. I'm probably wrong on that, here are more examples — [one](https://web.archive.org/web/20131018053358if_/http://worldoftanks.ru/community/accounts/1304732-NeedHate/), [two](https://web.archive.org/web/20130806192901if_/http://worldoftanks.ru/community/accounts/122931-emperer/), [three](https://web.archive.org/web/20140621085715if_/http://worldoftanks.ru/community/accounts/11729634-yura833/).

I have attempted calculating the rotation angle for the left indicator using the formulas from [this React application](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-css-score-indicator-2dpfr), but it uses 180° scale while I have 60° with start point not being at leftmost position.

Providing code-way solution of the problem is not essential, I'm looking for math-way solution which I'll adapt to language I use on my backend, but if you wish so, I'll accept answers in PHP, JS or Python 3.x syntax.

Comment: `y = (30 * x) - 30` if x is between 0-2.

Comment: @Christopher, if `x=1.13`, then the result matches (3.9°), but any other values, `x=1.8`, `x=0.87` return 24° (expected 25°) and -3.9° (expected -6.5°). Is it possible that the left side (or even both?) of k/d scale is non-linear and does not have 0.1 per notch, or my thoughts on scale peaks are wrong?

Comment: The results are correct if the scale is linear.  The devations may come from the rounding. For example: `11319335 / 10530420 = 1.0749177....` and if you only use 1.07 the result will be lower. -- It also could be, that the angle is automatically set to the "next step" like everything > 2 and <= 4 = 4.0, > 4 and <= 6.5 = 6.5 and so on...